# Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape= (2794,0)) while a minimum of 1 is required by check_pair_arrays

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca, grid-search

I am trying to get the right hyperparameters for my Kernel PCA. I have a dataset of (4191,193) dimensions.
However, when I run the following code, I get the error stating my array has no features.

```
def my_scorer(estimator,X,y=None):
    X_reduced = estimator.Transform(X)
    X_preimage = estimator.inverse_transform(X_reduced)
    return -1 * mean_squared_error(X,X_preimage) 

param_grid = [{"gamma" : np.linspace(0.03,0.05,10),
                "kernel" : ["rbf", "sigmoid", "linear", "poly"]
             }]
df = pd.read_csv(CSVfile,sep=";",encoding='latin-1',dtype='a')
X = df.drop("Class",axis=1)
y = df['Class']

kpca = KernelPCA(fit_inverse_transform=True, n_jobs=-1
grid_search = GridSearchCV(kpca,param_grid,cv=3,scoring=my_scorer)
grid_search.fit(X,y)
print(grid_search.best_params_)
```

I have tried debugging but the program enters into sklearn\utils\validation.py file then runs in a loop and stops answering to my debug commands. I hope you guys can help me.

X.shape returns (4191,193)
y.shape returns (4191,)

The error code I am receiving :

```
In [12]: runfile('C:/Users/TS2_SPE/Documents/Radja/moteur_apprentissage/gridSearchCV.py', wdir='C:/Users/TS2_SPE/Documents/Radja/moteur_apprentissage')
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py:530: FutureWarning: From version 0.22, errors during fit will result in a cross validation score of NaN by default. Use error_score='raise' if you want an exception raised or error_score=np.nan to adopt the behavior from version 0.22.FutureWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-12-ff26b3784908>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/TS2_SPE/Documents/Radja/moteur_apprentissage/gridSearchCV.py', wdir='C:/Users/TS2_SPE/Documents/Radja/moteur_apprentissage')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
  File "C:/Users/TS2_SPE/Documents/Radja/moteur_apprentissage/gridSearchCV.py", line 35, in <module> grid_search.fit(X,y)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py", line 688, in fit self._run_search(evaluate_candidates)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py", line 1149, in _run_search evaluate_candidates(ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py", line 667, in evaluate_candidates cv.split(X, y, groups)))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 924, in __call__ while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 759, in dispatch_one_batch self._dispatch(tasks)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 716, in _dispatch job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py", line 182, in apply_async result = ImmediateResult(func)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py", line 549, in __init__self.results = batch()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 225, in __call__ for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 225, in <listcomp> for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 516, in _fit_and_score estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\decomposition\kernel_pca.py", line 283, in fit self._fit_inverse_transform(X_transformed, X)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\decomposition\kernel_pca.py", line 255, in _fit_inverse_transform K = self._get_kernel(X_transformed)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\decomposition\kernel_pca.py", line 180, in _get_kernel **params)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\pairwise.py", line 1745, in pairwise_kernels return _parallel_pairwise(X, Y, func, n_jobs, **kwds)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\pairwise.py", line 1213, in _parallel_pairwise for s in gen_even_slices(_num_samples(Y), effective_n_jobs(n_jobs)))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 934, in __call__ self.retrieve()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 833, in retrieve self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 657, in get raise self._value
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 121, in worker result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py", line 567, in __call__ return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 225, in __call__ for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 225, in <listcomp> for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\pairwise.py", line 1194, in _dist_wrapper dist_matrix[:, slice_] = dist_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\pairwise.py", line 914, in sigmoid_kernel X, Y = check_pairwise_arrays(X, Y)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\pairwise.py", line 112, in check_pairwise_arraysestimator=estimator)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 558, in check_array context))
ValueError: Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(2794, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required by check_pairwise_arrays.
```

Comment: Please, provide the output you get. Furthermore, the output of `X.shape`. Thanks.

Comment: X.shape returns me (4191,193). And this is the overall error I am getting -  "ValueError : Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(2794,0)) while a minimum of 1 is required by check_pairwise_arrays".   Check_pairwise_arrays is a function from sklearns/utils/validation.py

Comment: What about `y.shape`?

Comment: y.shape returns (4191,)

Comment: Then, provide the full error output in your own question. Thanks.

Comment: done. Thank you for taking your time !